# Calendar view with SwiftDate

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, calendar

I downloaded the project from github Swift Date (https://github.com/haginile/SwiftDate) how do I import the calendar in a view in xcode and consequently display the calendar?
Thank you all for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the source code and created a new project, then dragged all source files to the new project. I added a function and tested it. It worked.

```
func test() {
    var d1 = Date(year : 2014, month : 5, day : 15)
    var d2 = Date(string : "2014-05-15")
    d1 = d1 + 1
    if (d2 > d1) {
        println("d2 is greater than d1")
    } else {
        println("d2 is smaller than d1")
    }
}
```

Comment: At this time they are not in front of the computer but as soon as I get home I try if your example is right for my case. Anyway thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry if I answer only now but have not had a free moment. Thanks for the help but I just can not get it to work, I'll try with some other solution.